# Fast algorithm to find pairs

Tags: algorithm

What is the fastest algorithm to make pairs of object from two arrays. Every object has two two attributes: k and l.

Requirements:

1. Every object from array A must make pair with one object from array B
2. sizes of arrays are equal
3. A.k > B.k && A.l > B.l (a condition for each pair)

Comment: The lowest compared to what, specifically?  Are you trying to minimize the sum across all pairs?  Is reuse acceptable?

Comment: @Makoto: OP is searching for the bipartite pairing graph with the lowest total error (with error being the absolute delta between attributes of A & B). Looks very much like homework though, imho.

Comment: @Regexident:  Okay, that seems practical.  Further, it doesn't really matter if it's a homework question or not around here, so long as it's on-topic.

Comment: @Makoto _Are you trying to minimize the sum across all pairs? Is reuse acceptable?_ Yes, yes :)

Comment: Any ideas how to solve it?